# Setting URL in UploadCollectionItem in UI5 1.38.4

Tags: sapui5

What parameters are mandatory for an UploadCollectionItem with the URL parameter set will show the file when the filename is clicked.

I am using a factory to handle files coming from different locations.

```
attachmentFactory(sId, context) {
  const modelObj = context.getModel().getProperty(context.getPath());
  const uploadListItem = new SAPUploadCollectionItem();

  // If __metadata exists, attachment entry is from odata, if not then it's a FileEntry object.
  if (modelObj.__metadata) {
    uploadListItem.setFileName(modelObj.FILE_NAME);
    uploadListItem.setMimeType(modelObj.MIME_CODE);
    uploadListItem.setUrl("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Koala_climbing_tree.jpg");
  }
  else {
    uploadListItem.setFileName(modelObj.name);
    uploadListItem.setMimeType(modelObj.type);
    uploadListItem.setUrl("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Koala_climbing_tree.jpg");
  }
  return uploadListItem;
}
```

I get an exception in UI5 when I press the link in the function

```
UploadCollection.prototype._triggerLink = function(oEvent, oContext) {
    var iLine = null;
    var aId;

    if (oContext.editModeItem) {
        //In case there is a list item in edit mode, the edit mode has to be finished first.
        sap.m.UploadCollection.prototype._handleOk(oEvent, oContext, oContext.editModeItem, true);
        if (oContext.sErrorState === "Error") {
            //If there is an error, the link of the list item must not be triggered.
            return this;
        }
        oContext.sFocusId = oEvent.getParameter("id");
    }
    aId = oEvent.oSource.getId().split("-");
    iLine = aId[aId.length - 2];
    sap.m.URLHelper.redirect(oContext.aItems[iLine].getProperty("url"), true);
};
```

oContext.aItems is an array but the source.getId() value is "__item9-ta_filenameHL" so __item9 is not found in oContext.aItems

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm setting up my UploadCollectionItem incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the sId of the UploadCollectionItem to be the sId that was passed into the factory.